# /dev/md2 already in use and failed to start in degraded mode

Tags: server, raid

A server I am working on has three raids. The first two raids are raid1 and run on two drives (two partitions). One is / and one is swap. Both of these function 100%.

However it is the third raid that I am having trouble with. It has 10 1TB drives in a raid10 configuration. These drives are housed in a Sans Digital EliteStor and connected by a highpoint rocketraid. The rocketraid's drivers did not work with the installation, but I could see the drives just fine. So I used a mdraid. On an occasional reboot while testing I have noticed that it will stop with these error messages:

```
md/raid10:md2: not enough operational mirrors.
md: pers->run() failed ...
```

Then it is followed by this strange message:

```
mdadm: the device /dev/md2 is already in use
could not start raid in degraded mode
starting shell
```

This raid serves as the /var where I intend to put both a website and host a fairly large database. Here is the catch I have to send this about 200 miles away where it will be hosted, and each time it does this I cannot ssh into the box. Once I reboot it it appears to be fine for random number of times, but usually no more then three times.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Turns out that the raid card I used only has 4 external connections. So it would only recognize 4 drives in the raid at a time.